# What does jquery's scrollLeft function do

Tags: jquery

What does `scrollLeft()` function of jquery do? What does it mean when I write `$(window).scrollLeft()`,`$(window).scrollLeft(1300)`, `$("div.test").scrollLeft()` and `$("div.test").scrollLeft(1000)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about the [CSS `.scrollLeft()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) method?

> Description: Get the current horizontal position of the scroll bar for the first element in the set of matched elements.
>
> The horizontal scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very left, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.

In other words, it tells you and lets you set how many pixels the page (or an element) is scrolled horizontally.

Comment: @Sayem Yes, if these divs are scrollable (have a scrollbar).

Comment: @Sayem Apply some fixed width of {x} pixels and `overflow: auto` or `overflow: scroll` and insert content that is wider than {x} pixels.